# Keras LSTM Continue training after save

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i'm working on a LSTM model and i'd like to save it and continue later with extra data as it accumulates.
My problem is that after save the model and load it again next time i run the script, the prediction is completely wrong, it just mimics the data i entered into it.

Here's the model initialization:

```
# create and fit the LSTM network
if retrain == 1:
    print "Creating a newly retrained network."
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(inputDimension, input_shape=(1, inputDimension)))
    model.add(Dense(inputDimension, activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)
    model.save("model.{}.h5".format(interval))
else:
    print "Using an existing network."
    model = load_model("model.{}.h5".format(interval))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)
    model.save("model.{}.h5".format(interval))
    del model
    model = load_model("model.{}.h5".format(interval))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

The first dataset, when retrain is set to 1, is around 10 000 entries with around 3k epoch and 5% batch size.
The second dataset is a single entry data. as in one row, with again 3k epochs and batch_size=1

**Solved**

I was reloading the scaler incorrectly:

```
scaler = joblib.load('scaler.{}.data'.format(interval))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
```

Correct:

```
scaler = joblib.load('scaler.{}.data'.format(interval))
dataset = scaler.transform(dataset)
```

fit_transform recalculates the multipliers for the scaled values, that means there will be an offset from the original data.

Answer (score 1):

From the functional [keras model api](https://keras.io/models/model/) for model.fit():

> initial_epoch: Integer. Epoch at which to start training (useful for resuming a previous training run).

Setting this parameter might solve your problem.

I think the source of the problem is the adaptive learning rate from adam. During training the learning rate anturally declines for more finetuning of the model. When you retrain your model with only one sample the weight updates are much too big (because of the resetted learning rate) which can totally destroy your previous weights.

If initial_epoch is not good, than try to start your second training with a lower learning rate.

Comment: Could it be possible that this is due to the scaler? 
I'm doing scaler.fit_transform on the dataset, at the first dataset the data varies from 6000-8000, but since the second dataset is only a single value, the scaler is scaling the data specifically for that same value, not for the same range as the first dataset.

Comment: This can also be problematic but seems unrelated. In generell if you just do one weight update it should not destroy your accuracy even if the data is wrongly scaled. For the the scaler problem: Can you pickle the scaler object and call it without fit in the scond run?

Comment: Without fit, the predictions look fine, also tried initial_epochs and 0.001 learning rate. didn't help. The weird thing is, when i load the model, and display the learning rate, it's automatically 0.

Comment: There is no problem with training, if i change the dataset size then the prediction will work, train or no train.

Comment: I just saw another thing: Why do you compile the model after load_model? I don't thin this is necessary. Maybe this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Hmm, probably yes. But the problem got solved, thanks for your thoughts!